# existence of integral of one form.

Tags: differential-geometry

One form is essentially a linear mapping of a vector field to the euclidean space.
In case of functions , for existence of integral we need just continuity and boundedness .
I am not able to understand why for an integral of one form to exist we need it to be smooth.
please explain me.

Answer (score 3):

Often, the theory of integration of differential forms is done in a context where all the objects involved are smooth (so you are working on a smooth manifold, the form is smooth, etc) but this doesn't have to be the case.

Assuming your manifold is at least $C^1$, you can talk about continuous one-forms $\omega$ which are one-forms which can be represented locally as $a_i(x^1, \dots, x^n) dx^i$ where the coefficient functions $a^i$ are only continuous. Then, one can define the integral of $\omega$ along a piecewise $C^1$ curve $\gamma \colon [a,b] \rightarrow M$ as

$$ \int_{\gamma} \omega := \int_a^b \omega(\dot{\gamma}(t)) \, dt. $$

If the image of the curve $\gamma$ lies in a coordinate patch with coordinates $x^i$ and $\omega = a_i dx^i$, in that patch, then

$$ \int_{\gamma} \omega = \int_a^b a_i(\gamma(t)) \dot{\gamma}^i(t) \, dt $$

where $\gamma^i(t) = x^i(\gamma(t))$. The integrand is then piecewise continuous and so the integral is well-defined. This argments extends to the general case where the image of $\gamma$ doesn't lie in a single coordinate system by covering the image with finitely many coordinate patches.

Even the assumptions above can be weakened considerably and you can talk about one-forms with locally integrable coefficients, etc.